# WPF MVVM How to re-center application window after view changes?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, centering

I'm working on a very simple application using native WPF and MVVM.  The main "shell" view uses what I believe is a common basic pattern, in which it contains a ContentControl that is databound to the active viewmodel, which injects the view through data templates.  This is an abbreviated version of what it looks like:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ShellViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DbConfigViewModel}">
        <local:DbConfigView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:AuthenticationViewModel}">
        <local:AuthenticationView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

This window is set to auto-size based on the view, and is set to start up centered.  This works fine for the initial view.  Some views are much larger though, and it becomes a UI issue when they become active.  What I need to occur is have the application re-center itself whenever a view changes.

What I've tried so far is to databind the Left and Top properties of the main Window, like this:

```
<Window (....)
    Width="auto" Height="auto"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Left="{Binding WindowLeft}"
    Top="{Binding WindowTop}">
```

My navigation is tied to a method within the main Windows's viewmodel, so in that method, after the new viewmodel is set to the CurrentViewModel property, I then call this method:

```
    private void CenterWindow()
    {
        Rect workArea = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea;
        WindowLeft = (workArea.Width - Application.Current.MainWindow.Width) / 2 + workArea.Left;
        WindowTop = (workArea.Height - Application.Current.MainWindow.Height) / 2 + workArea.Top;
    }
```

This seems like it should work, but what appears to be happening is that the MainWindow.Width and Height have not yet been adjusted, so it is centering based on the previous view rather than the one I just instantiated.

So is there some event or other place to call this code so that it occurs after the new view is rendered?   Is this even the correct approach?

Comment: if you're sure the window cannot be resized by the user, I guess you should be able to do this by creating an OnSizeChanged override for the main window and calling CenterWindow there ? Note: MSDN describes  `WorkArea` as *Gets the size of the work area on the primary display monitor.* so your method will not always do what you expect it to on multiple monitor systems

Comment: I had thought about the OnSizeChanged event, but I didn't want to interfere with the client's ability to resize the window. As a last resort we will think about removing that ability, but I'd like to find another way if possible.  Thanks for the tip about WorkArea, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Can you show me *any professional application* that has this behaviour? I'm guessing that you can't and that is because this is a bad idea. Resizing an application `Window` (unless it is a child `Window`) should *not* be the concern of the development team. Make a fluid UI, which fits all of the views as best as you can and leave the size of the `Window` up to the user... as it was *meant* to be. I'd say that the fact that you are asking this question points to the fact that you have something wrong with the design of your UI.

Comment: @Sheridan While I would normally agree with you, this particular application is a very simple utility that I am developing for our engineering services team.  The meat of the application is a single view, however I need them to go through 2 brief dialogs before getting there.  Rather than using traditional dialog services, I figured it would be simple enough to just swap out the view as I've shown.  This was a quick and simple way to get the task finished, but I just have to solve this little nuance.

Comment: That's the bit that I can't understand... a fluid WPF UI will fit itself into whatever space has been provided by the containing `Window`... it seems as though *that* is what you're *actually* missing and how you should fixing *this little nuance*, as you call it.

Comment: @Sheridan I would like the first two "dialogs" to actually look like dialogs, so that the window is sized to the child controls.  If I size everything to the main view's size, the first two dialogs will be a couple of input fields sitting mostly on a lot of white space.  Perhaps view injection is not going to work in this case and I need to re-implement them as actual dialogs.

Comment: Dude... just use child `Window`s like everyone else and save yourself some trouble.

Answer (score 4):

You need to subscribe to SizeChanged in your window then:

```
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PreviousSize == e.NewSize)
        return;

    var w = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
    var h = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;

    this.Left = (w - e.NewSize.Width) / 2;
    this.Top = (h - e.NewSize.Height) / 2;
}
```

You can use interaction events if you want it in your viewModel

Comment: What if the window is not on the primary screen?